# Google Cloud Platform compute error rate graph at 100% percent

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-compute-engine, google-compute-api

My Google Forms add-on has a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) project attached to it, with various APIs enabled.  The GCP APIs and Services dashboard has a graph for traffic and errors.  Both the traffic and errors graphs show a line for "compute" and the "compute" error rate is 100% percent.  But I have no idea where this is coming from.  Attached is an image of my GCP APIs and Services page.  It shows the APIs that I have enabled.  I don't remember enabling anything for "compute."  And there is no API that states anything about "compute."
Any information would be appreciated.

[image: Google Cloud Platform compute traffic]

[image: Errors Computer with Mouse hover]

Comment: Put the tip of your mouse on the line. You will see a box appear with more information.

Comment: When I hover the mouse over the Errors line, all is states is: `compute 100.00%`  Other than that, there is no extra information.  See updated answer with second image from hovering the mouse over the orange line.

Comment: I don't have an answer, just to add a bit more data though I have the exact same thing but I only have the Maps and Places APIs enabled. No other credentials exist, can't see anywhere that tells me what is causing the problems.

Comment: Any update on this? I just ran into same issue.. can't figure out what this compute stands for.

Comment: I still don't have any answers.